# Can 'surgery' be a count noun in the sense of 'medical procedure'?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

This is something that has bothered me for a long time. Several years ago a remember noticing in the media a shift from using "An operation" to "A surgery" when talking about someone who was undergoing a medical procedure.

Now, to my ears "A surgery" sounded patently wrong. To me it sounded a lot like saying "A water". In the sense of 'medical procedure', *surgery* is a mass noun to me, and using it as a count noun is ungrammatical.

I'm entirely prepared to be told to go away and stop being so ridiculous. This could all, in the end, entirely be the ramblings of someone who sees the English language in his own peculiar way. But is it just me?

Is "a surgery" a legitimate and commonly accepted use of the word?

Comment: This must be a BrE thing. American media don't use "a surgery". Thank goodness! You're 100% right that it's awful.

Comment: @DanBron Australian english to be precise :) although funnily enough, I seem to remember it stemming from an American news report that was shown over here once - I'm so glad it's not a common thing :D

Comment: ***Surgery***: medical operation is actually uncountable referring to :[U] *the treatment of injuries or diseases in people or animals by cutting open the body and removing or repairing the damaged part*:
The patient had/underwent surgery on his heart.
He made a good recovery after surgery to remove a brain tumour.  The countable noun refers to  [C or U] UK (US office) a place where you can go to ask advice from or receive treatment from a doctor or dentist. It is just a wrong use of the term

Comment: BrE tends to use 'a procedure' or the mass usage 'underwent surgery' rather than 'a surgery', though the count noun has always been used for the place where you see your GP. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/surgery) (AmE as well as BrE versions) give the count usage for 'a procedure': **surgery**  [COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE] medical treatment in which a doctor cuts open someone’s body:
_He had to undergo heart bypass surgery.
doctors who perform several surgeries a day_. It does not label it as BrE (but it does for the 'office' polyseme).

Comment: @Josh61 'It is just a wrong use of the term': not according to Macmillan.

Comment: What you're calling ‘indefinite nouns’ are actually called variously [**non-count nouns, uncountable nouns, or mass nouns**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). _Surgery_ in the sense of ‘medical procedure’ does indeed sound odd to me as a count noun, yes—though it is perfectly fine as a count noun in the sense ‘doctor’s office’ or ‘place where surgical operations are carried out’ (“Dr. Smith has two surgeries: one in Brooklyn and one in Manhattan”).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - surgery: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surgery

Comment: From [Grammar as Interactional Resources in Spontaneous **Korean** Conversations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iMUDT9PDLhoC&pg=PA224&dq=%22had+a+surgery+last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HmhcVYb9MYerU4yzgNgN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22had%20a%20surgery%20last%22&f=false) *Speaker G says that A's mother **had a surgery** last winter.* It's (still?!) non-standard, but just as we Brits have to keep reminding the Germans to stop referring to ***a software***, the Aussies will need to correct their would-be English speaking neighbours.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you so much for that! It has been driving me mad trying to find out what the term for it was! Now I have a word for it when I tell my friends off :D

Comment: @Josh61 Even the editors of OED give the caveat that non-inclusion of a string etc in their unrivalled work does not guarantee it is not a word. ODO contains _far_ less material than OED. I'm sure that the count usage of the operation sense of 'surgery' will be included in OED; though it's not really common in the UK, it's not uncommon either.

Comment: @FF It's not non-standard according to either my perceptions, or, more importantly, Macmillan.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/surgery. To me it is a common misuse of the term.

Comment: I'll edit the question so it's more concrete

Comment: @Edwin: Well, we wouldn't be talking about it at all if it were considered "standard" by *most* native speakers. Obviously the specific reason why that's not the case is simply a matter of established idiomatic usage, and there will certainly be a number of perfectly competent speakers who feel differently. But relatively speaking [it's not at all common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+for+a+surgery%2Cwent+for+surgery&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20for%20surgery%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ...Google Books claims 649 instances of *went for surgery*, but only 5 for *went for **a** surgery*.

Comment: Try Googling ' "underwent two surgeries" -Jimmy'. 888 000 'hits'; US as well as UK examples; various registers.

Comment: @AndrewLeach is this rewording better? Can it be taken off hold

Comment: ...and [here's the evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=performed+several+surgeries&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperformed%20several%20surgeries%3B%2Cc0) that the "non-standard" usage is largely a recent phenomenon.

Comment: ... So is 'googling'.

Comment: If this is essentially a question about the difference between count and non-count nouns, or the grey areas, it's a duplicate. If it's a question about the acceptability of the count usage of surgery = surgical procedure, it's either general reference (Macmillan licenses the usage; though perhaps someone could add the OED position) or invites opinion-based answers.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think it's *just* a matter of opinion. Okay, so some native speakers (incl. Edwin, obviously! :) have no problem with the usage. But I'm quite certain the vast majority of Anglophones *don't* use ***a** surgery* to mean *a surgical procedure*, and it's not difficult to produce statistical evidence to prove that. In the final analysis, *all* language use is a matter of opinion, but fortunately we mostly have the same/similar opinions about valid use of expressions, or we wouldn't be able to communicate at all.

Comment: @Phill I’ve taken the liberty of editing your question to make it less opinion-based. Also, since the established terminology for count and non-count nouns has now been established, I’ve cut out the parts of the question that were about that—that’s not really related to _surgery_, after all. If you don’t approve of my edit, feel free to roll it back or switch it up again. :-)

Comment: @FF I'd say _synallagmatic_ wouldn't be described as being 'standard' by _most_ native speakers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yep, I'm happy with that. The main reason for asking was to learn the terms related to count nouns, but I'm equally interested in the discussion about "a surgery" since it's been bothering and I do hear it at least as frequently as "an operation" and other terms that sound better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find three definitions of *surgery* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) for which the plural *surgeries* seems eminently reasonable:

> **3 a** *Brit* **:** a physician's or dentist's office **b :** a room or area where surgery is performed **4** [...] **b :** OPERATION

That a room where physicians receive and examine or operate on patients may be called "a surgery" and that multiple such rooms may be called "surgeries" seem unexceptionable to me. An entry for "a surgery" appears in John Kersey, [*A New English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zFBgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT280&dq=%22a+surgery%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-nplVbq6B8KrsAWHyIPYBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20surgery%22&f=false), eighth edition (1772):

> *A* **Surgery**, a *place* or *room where a surgeon performs his operations.*

And Rowland Jackson, [*A Physical Dissertation on Drowning*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tdvp2IXtfGEC&pg=PA71&dq=%22a+surgery%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-nplVbq6B8KrsAWHyIPYBA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20surgery%22&f=false) (1746) gives this instance of the phrase in action:

> The Surgeons of the Town having obtained his Body, in order to make a Skeleton, brought it into **a Surgery**, where they left it upon a Table ; but when they came next Day to dissect: it, they were surprized to find the Man not only alive, but in good Health, and pissing in the Chimney for want, as he said, of a Chamber-pot.

Definition 4b of *surgery* (the single word "OPERATION") is presumably a more hotly disputed case. And yet that definition has been appearing in editions of the Merriam-Webster Collegiate series for more than 50 years—since the Seventh Edition (1963).

A Google Books search finds this early instance from John Aitken, [*Systematic Elements of the Theory and Practice of Surgery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-x0UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA291&dq=%22a+surgery%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GXllVdfcMcWZsAWB-ICgCA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22a%20surgery%22&f=false) (1779):

> Spina ventosa indicates **a Surgery** nearly similar to that proposed for Caries [chapter reference omitted]. Trepanation may produce the most salutary effects before the lamellated portion of the Bone be eroded.

Here, "a Surgery" seems to mean "a form of surgery." But it could just as well mean "an operation." And in this example, from Russell Trall, [*The Hydropathic Encyclopedia: A System of Hydropathy and Hygiene*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q2oEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA256&dq=%22this+surgery%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=94JlVf75EcfjsAX_7YCICw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22this%20surgery%22&f=false) (1853):

> DROPSY OF THE SPINE.—This affection is mostly congenital ; it consists of a soft fluctuating tumor on the spine, from fluid accumulated within the coats of the spinal cord, protruding externally in consequence of some portion of the vertebral column being defective. It is generally fatal, although a cure has taken place spontaneously in a few instances, and several cases have been reported as cured by repeatedly puncturing the sac with a fine needle. With the exception of **this surgery**, if deemed advisable, the proper course is to attend to the general health, and "trust to nature."

the equivalence between "this surgery" and "this operation" seems clear. Is the phrase "this surgery" less offensive to some sensitive persons' ears than "a surgery" is? I wouldn't be surprised if that proved to be the case—and if it did, it seems to me, instances of "this surgery" might have acted as the advance party of Achaeans entering the city and then unlocking it to the subsequent depredations of "a surgery."

An Ngram chart of "a surgery" (blue line) versus "this surgery" (red line) for the period 1700–2000 suggests that "a surgery" broke out of its fairly stable frequency between the 1870s and the 1930s when "this surgery began its steep ascent during the 1940s:

> [image]

As the chart indicates, despite the rapid increase in frequency of "a surgery" since about 1970, the frequency of "this surgery" has grown at an even faster rate. The plural form surgeries (green line), meanwhile, has dwarfed both "a surgery" and "this surgery" in frequency, again starting around 1970:

> [image]

And interestingly, whereas recent instances in the Google Books search results for "a surgery" skew heavily toward instances where "a surgery" is followed by a noun such as "room" or "center," many recent examples of "surgeries" clearly use it in the sense of "operations"—in constructions such as "[vascular **surgeries** are frequent features](https://books.google.com/books?id=6pWQKi0ufbAC&pg=PA347&dq=%22surgeries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YYxlVdjCBsOCsAXBqYHwBQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22surgeries%22&f=false)..." and "[By clustering **surgeries** with similar duration variability characteristics](https://books.google.com/books?id=QCmMShZQWOQC&pg=PA125&dq=%22surgeries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YYxlVdjCBsOCsAXBqYHwBQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22surgeries%22&f=false)..." and "[adverse event rates among glaucoma **surgeries**](https://books.google.com/books?id=2qVJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22surgeries%22&dq=%22surgeries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TI1lVeuyEcuMsAWw7oCIBQ&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAjgU)..."

It thus appears that dissatisfaction with "a surgery" may be somewhat misdirected, since the terms "this surgery" and "surgeries" show up much more frequently in the Google Books database in the reprehended sense of "operation[s]" than "a surgery" does.

Comment: Wow. Looks like I might have to stop telling my friends off!