# Using "from" and "to"

Tags: grammaticality

I want to express that the doctors I shadow do surgery on patients who are newborns all the way to patients who are adolescents but I feel like this sentence has a grammatical error. Can someone help me fix it?
"I shadow pediatric surgeons as they complete clinical rounds and perform surgeries on children from newborns to adolescents."

Comment: ... and perform surgeries on children (from newborns to adolescents).

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. We don't do proofreading; could you edit your question to indicate where you think the grammatical error is and why it's wrong? (For as much as my opinion is worth, I can't see anything wrong with it **grammatically,** although it makes it sound as if they operate on children during their rounds, and "perform surgeries" is not idiomatic.)

Comment: @Andrew That was last week. 109 000 Google hits for "perform surgeries"; I suspect most of them are from medical sources.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm. I had to get to page 8 of the results before I got to a .uk citation, and that was for the Daily Mail. So: not idiomatic in British English, anyway.

Comment: I think you've missed out a comma ~ perform surgeries on children, from newborns to adolescents ~ but otherwise the sentence is fine.

Comment: @Andrew The [Can 'surgery' be a count noun in the sense of 'medical procedure'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247540/can-surgery-be-a-count-noun-in-the-sense-of-medical-procedure) thread cites dictionary (Macmillan, M-W) support for the count usage. At least one of these includes English corpus data.

Answer (score 1):

I shadow the clinical rounds of paediatric surgeons.

"Paediatric" means "related to children", which means "related to people from birth to puberty".

Comment: I like "from birth to puberty" a lot.  I would include that phrase in the sentence, though, since the OP wants to be very explicit about the wide range of ages in the clinical experience.