# Article usage in two sentences

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Two sentences:

1. She underwent emergency surgery.
2. I had to undergo a medical examination when I started my new job.

Why in sentence one the article "an" is not required before "emergency surgery", but sentence two requires the "a" before "medical examination"?

In sentence one, I could put "an" before "emergency surgery", but it isn't required.  Why is that?

My most gracious appreciation for anyone who can offer some insight.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the title should be "Article usage in two sentences".  I made "article" plural.  Typo :(

Comment: "Surgery" can be either. ["Colorectal Resection is a surgery to remove a section of the large intestine"](https://www.womans.org/our-services/surgery/common-surgeries) or ["What's It Like to Have Surgery?"](https://kidshealth.org/en/teens/having-sugery.html) Typically, we do not include the indefinite article when we are saying someone is going to "have" or "undergo" surgery. Likewise, "examination" can be used with or without the article. [All patients or their guardians gave informed consent to undergo examination and surgical treatment.](https://ludwig.guru/s/or+undergo+examinations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can 'surgery' be a count noun in the sense of 'medical procedure'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247540/can-surgery-be-a-count-noun-in-the-sense-of-medical-procedure) The fact is that 'surgery' is rarely used in a count fashion, and rarely used with 'a' (not quite the same thing) ... while 'examination' is usually used as a count usage in these areas. 'I needed two examinations, as the first one was inconclusive.'

Answer (score 1):

*To have surgery* is the grammatical form; *to have *a surgery* is not grammatical under most circumstances. That’s because
the noun *surgery* is more often used as a mass noun than it is as a count noun.

So you wouldn’t use the indefinite article before it, just like you don’t before *peace* in “We will have peace in our times.”

It’s more common to say that you’ve had surgery twice than that you’ve had two surgeries. If you need a count noun, we usually use *an operation* or sometimes *a surgical procedure*. You’ve had two operations or two surgical procedures.

Comment: Some citations might help here, as there are plenty of examples of both "a surgery" being used and "examination" being used without the article, so there is clearly some rule at play for when we treat these as uncountable.

Comment: Thank you to all involved for answering my question and leading me to other discussions regarding the topic.  Stay safe :)